# Get config of other environment in Grails 2.*

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-test

I'm running Grails 2.1.1, and i'm looking for a way to get the value of variable set in production while i'm running on test environment.
The config file :

```
development {
  config.url = "http://local"
}
test {
  config.url = "http://test.lan"
}
production {
  config.url = "http://prod.lan"
}
```

The only way i know to get config variables is grailsApplication.config.url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard config setup only looks at the current environment. `Holders` has the same current config as `grailsApplication`. You have to slurp the config again. Try using `ConfigurationHelper`. A spock test is below. (Note the sometimes doubled `config.config` is because the first `config` is the property (or short name for `getConfig()` method) and your key contains the second `config`.)

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin
import spock.lang.Specification

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.cfg.ConfigurationHelper

@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class ConfigSpec extends Specification {

    void "test prod config"() {
        def configSlurper = ConfigurationHelper.getConfigSlurper('production',null)
        def configObject = configSlurper.parse(grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass(grailsApplication.CONFIG_CLASS))

        expect:
        configObject.config.url == "http://prod.lan"
    }

    void "test dev config"() {
        def configSlurper = ConfigurationHelper.getConfigSlurper('development',null)
        def configObject = configSlurper.parse(grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass(grailsApplication.CONFIG_CLASS))

        expect:
        configObject.config.url == "http://local"
    }

    void "test grailsApplication config"() {
        expect:
        grailsApplication.config.config.url == "http://test.lan"
    }

    void "test Holders config"() {
        expect:
        grails.util.Holders.config.config.url == "http://test.lan"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Holders](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.1.4/api/grails/util/Holders.html): https://gist.github.com/mathifonseca/ab443f1502bfd9461943

```
import grails.util.Holders

class FooService {

     def foo() {

          def devUrl = Holders.config.url

          assert devUrl == "http://local"     
     }

}
```